# I want to call a php function which invokes other function to run in background even if the page/browser is closed

Tags: php, background, exec

I want to call a php function which invokes other function to run in background even if the page/browser is closed and process keeps running .I have written the function which creates PDF for some report i want to keep it running even if browser is closed or paged is refreshed

Comment: try `cron` for auto hit `function`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cronjob to run a function on server after a specific time. Many hosting companies provide cronjob services and there are also free cronjob providers.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how your source code works. Your code will stop executing if your entire page is rendered by PHP (no JavaScript async requests) when you close the browser.

One way is to make an **async** Ajax call on page load which calls the desired method. Another way is to work with cron.

Comment: How to trigger function in background after ajax call

Comment: REST is your friend